# Closed unit ball is a retract of $R^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was asked whether a closed unit ball is a retract of the euclidean space $R^2$. I think the answer is yes and the retraction might be defined as follows: for all the points in $R^2$ join them with the origin by a straight line, then wherever it will cut the ball first that would be the image of that point under the function.

This is just an idea but I want a rigorous proof. Can somebody tell me? Any other function is also welcome.

Comment: Hint: Let $w$ be a vector such that $|w|>1$ and $v$ the corresponding unit vector.  Consider the retraction given by $(1-t)w+tv$ for $t\in[0,1]$.  For points inside the disk, they should be fixed by the retraction.

Comment: The function you have defined is simply $$x\mapsto \begin{cases} x &: \|x\| \leq 1 \\ \frac{x}{\|x\|} &: \|x\| > 1\end{cases}$$ where $\|(x,y)\| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. You now have to check that this is continuous (use the fact that $x\mapsto \|x\|$ is continuous by the triange inequality)

Comment: @MichaelBurr that's a deformation retract, which is more than is needed.